# Responding to interactive programs in bash with python subprocess

Tags: python, bash

I have the bash script like the one below below. When you run it, it asks you for your name and then greets you:

```
#example.sh
printf "Hello, who is running this program? "

read -r USERNAME

echo Hi $USERNAME!
```

[image]

Is it possible to write a python script that can **1.** Run `sh example.sh` **2.** Respond `python` to the prompt for a name, and **3.** Read `Hi Larry!` back into python?

And just to clarify this is a hypothetical situation, so modifying the bash script is not the goal. Thank you!

Comment: Use expect and do it in tcl. Or search around to see if there's a similar tool in python.

Comment: To write this bash script in python? `username = input("Hello, who is running this program? ")` then `print(f"Hi {username}")`.  Though I'm not sure if that's what you were asking?

Comment: @v25 Thank you, but no. I am trying to interact with a bash program that already exists that requires user inputs to be given after the initial start of the program.

Comment: @Shawn Thank you, and I have used tcl a little bit, but It would really be best if I could get this accomplished in python. Is there a name for what I am trying to do so I could better refine my search?

Comment: python has module `pyexpect` which works like `expect` in `tcl`

Comment: eventually you may try to use functions in module `subprocess` - like `subprocess.run()` but it may be simpler to send all input (with new lines) at once without waiting for prompt.

Comment: but with supbrocess is problem that it get all output as single string `Hello, who is running this program? Hi Larry!` and it doesn't know which part was displayed as prompt - you will have to remove it later.

Comment: Thank you @furas! Pyexpect might do the trick! I had originally hoped subprocess would work but I didn't think it had the ability to interact with a program past initially running it. Was I mistaken?

Comment: I don't know what you means `interact`. In `subprocess.run()` you can use `input='Larry' and it will send it to script. And if you use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` then you can get all `output` with text `Hello, who is running this program? Hi Larry!` - and this may need to remove propmt. In `pyexpect` you will have to also define prompt which it has to skip. But if you want to send one `input` and get `output` before sending next `input` then `pyexpect` may be better.

Comment: I see! I hadn't realized subprocess worked that way. It might just be perfect for what I need!! Thank you @furas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know all answers for external script then you can use `subprocess.run()` and send all answers (with `\n`) as one string.

For test I use script which wait for two values `USERNAME` and `COLOR`

```
#example.sh
printf "Hello, who is running this program? "

read -r USERNAME

echo Hi $USERNAME!

printf "What is your favorite color? "

read -r COLOR

echo I like $COLOR too!
```

And I can use single string `"Larry\nBlue\n"` to send both values at once.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['sh', 'example.sh']

p = subprocess.run(cmd, input="Larry\nBlue\n".encode(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print( p.stdout.decode() )
```

It sends all at start and external script get first line as first answer, second line as second answer, etc. And when it finish then Python can get all output -

```
Hello, who is running this program? Hi Larry!
What is your favorite color? I like Blue too!
```

and you may have to remove elements which you don't need.

---

But if need to get output from first answer from external script to decide what to send as next answer then it makes problem.

It would need `subprocess.Popen()` to run and at the same time send input and read output. But there is other problem. If external script send line with `\n` then you can read it with `readline()` but if it doesn't send `\n` then `readline()` will wait for `\n` and it will block Python code. The same will be if it send one line but you will try to read 2 lines. Second `readline()` will block it. So you have to know how many lines it sends.

If you use `read()` then it will wait for end of data and it will also block Python. If you use `read(100)` and output will have 100 bytes (or more) then it will read 100 bytes (and rest will wait for next `read()` - but if it will have 99 bytes then `read(100)` will block Python.

You will have to know how may bytes to read or you have to know what text it may send and then you may `read(1)`, add it to buffer, and check if buffer has string which you expect. And this method uses `expect` and `pyexpect`.

---

First example with `readline()`

I use `example.sh` with `\n` in `printf`

```
printf "Hello, who is running this program? \n"

read -r USERNAME

echo Hi $USERNAME!

printf "What is your favorite color? \n"

read -r COLOR

echo I like $COLOR too!
```

Because `example.sh` send with `\n` so I remove `\n`

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['sh', 'example.sh']

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    
print('1 >>>', p.stdout.readline().decode().rstrip(), '<<<')
p.stdin.write("Larry!\n".encode())
p.stdin.flush()
print('2 >>>', p.stdout.readline().decode().rstrip(), '<<<')

print('1 >>>', p.stdout.readline().decode().rstrip(), '<<<')
p.stdin.write("Blue!\n".encode())
p.stdin.flush()
print('2 >>>', p.stdout.readline().decode().rstrip(), '<<<')
```

Result:

```
1 >>> Hello, who is running this program? <<<
2 >>> Hi Larry!! <<<
1 >>> What is your favorite color? <<<
2 >>> I like Blue! too! <<<
```

---

**EDIT:**

Example in `pexpect`

Similar to first version - I send all answers and get all output

```
import pexpect    

p = pexpect.spawn('sh script.sh')

p.sendline('Larry')
p.sendline('Blue')

p.expect(pexpect.EOF)  # wait for output

print(p.before.decode())
```

Similar to second example. Pexpect send input as output so it need extra `readline()

```
import pexpect    

p = pexpect.spawn('sh script.sh')

# ---
    
p.readline()
print('output 1 >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')

p.sendline('Larry')

p.readline()
print('input    >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')
p.readline()
print('output 2 >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')

# ---
    
p.readline()
print('output 1 >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')

p.sendline('Blue')

p.readline()
print('input    >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')
p.readline()
print('output 2 >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')

p.expect(pexpect.EOF)  # get rest to the end
print('end:', p.before.decode())
```

Instead of `readline()` it can use `expect(regex)` or `expect_exact(text)`

```
import pexpect    

p = pexpect.spawn('sh script.sh')

# ---
    
p.expect_exact('\r\n')
print('output 1 >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')

p.sendline('Larry')

p.expect_exact('\r\n')
print('input    >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')
p.expect_exact('\r\n')
print('output 2 >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')

# ---
    
p.expect_exact('\r\n')
print('output 1 >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')

p.sendline('Blue')

p.expect_exact('\r\n')
print('input    >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')
p.expect_exact('\r\n')
print('output 2 >>>', p.before.decode(), '<<<')

p.expect(pexpect.EOF)  # get rest to the end
print('end:', p.before.decode())
```

Comment: Thank you @furas, you've explained this is a very understandable way! I really appreciate the help!!

Comment: I try to do the same with `pexpect` to show difference but it needs time :)